# css how to make full height div with scroll support?

Tags: html, css

i can make full height divs but if content is longer than screen, div stays 100%, dont be full height.
so, i want to full height fixed div.
but i cannot do fixed.
i using this style;

```
<div id="left">
content
</div>
<div id="right">
content
</div>
```

and css;

```
html,body {height: 100%;background:#fff}
#left {height: 100%; width:200px; position:absolute; top: 0; left:0; background: black;}
#right {height: 100%; margin-left:200px; background: red;}
```

this is the result after i write too long content in #right div.

https://jsfiddle.net/hq21zmq8/

as you see, if content is longer than div, div isnt growing longer. how can i do fixed height ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow: scroll` if you want scrollbar

`#right {height: 100%; margin-left:200px; background: red; overflow: scroll;}`

or

`overflow: auto`

if the scrollbar should be hidden when not needed. as @Sverri M. Olsen said :)

Comment: Or `auto` if the scrollbar should be hidden when not needed.

Answer (score 3):

You want to take a look in the [overflow attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) in the css.

```
overflow: auto;
```

or if you always want a scroll bar

```
overflow: scroll;
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height` property if You want `div` to grow

```
#right {min-height: 100%; margin-left:200px; background: red;}
```

Or `overflow` if You want scrollbar

```
#right {height: 100%; margin-left:200px; background: red;overflow: auto;}
```

Comment: dont' forget the overflow

Answer (score 0):

add `overflow-y:scroll` to `#right` like

```
#right {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left:200px;
    background: red;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: scroll;` property

https://jsfiddle.net/hq21zmq8/7/

Comment: @eatik :) if u don't want the scrollbar to be visible for a div of small height, use `overflow: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following: `overflow-y: auto`

This should add a scrollbar if needed only.

Another thing is, I always use `height: 100vh`. Easier to work with in my opinion... But that's just a personal matter.

Comment: i used 100vh but it same as 100%. why i must use it ?

Comment: It's not mandatory to use it, don't know the exact pro's & contra's. Imo it's a little easier (don't know why exactly) :p https://teamtreehouse.com/community/percentages-vs-viewports